# html inside rails' if statement

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, if-statement

In my example I want RoR to display an image when I'm listening to Pearl Jam.
Winamp writes 'currently playing' info to np.txt.

```
<%= data = File.read("np.txt")
if data.include? "Pearl Jam"
<img src="space.jpg" alt="sagan"/> 
end
%>
```

However I'm not sure how to get HTML tags to work inside RoR code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
<% data = File.read "np.txt" %>
<% if data.include? "Pearl Jam" %>
  <img src="space.jpg" alt="sagan"/>
<% end %>
```

In ERB anything rendered outside of the <% %> tags is HTML.

ian.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an image tag.

```
<%- data = File.read "np.txt" -%>
<%= image_tag("space.jpg", :alt => "sagan") if data.include? "Pearl Jam" %>
```